# Include multiple blocks of Content in Assemble

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

I am migrating a web application from ASP.NET MVC to static pages using Assemble. I've been able to get pretty much everything figured out, but I'm running in to a problem with converting master pages to templates.

In the master pages I created multiple content regions, including one for css and scripts in the head, and a second region in the body for the content.  I don't see a way to include multiple regions directly in handlebars so I have tried using the helpers to include text.  Essentially moving the header text in to included files.

I found references to **{{glob}}** and **{{include}}** on the [helpers pages](http://assemble.io/helpers/helpers-content.html).  But they don't seem to be implemented.  I looked in the helper library and couldn't find them there either.

I tried using **{{include filename}}**, but I get the message: *"Warning: Missing helper: 'include' Use --force to continue."*

I tried using **{{glob filename}}** but I get the message : "Warning: undefined is not a function Use --force to continue."

I did the same thing using **{{md filename}}** and **{{embed filename}}** and they both work, but not quite what I needed.

If there's a better way to do this, or you could give me a fix I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@skeeve check out the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800813/assemble-multiple-points-of-content-insertion-in-layout)

We have some new layout helpers that would be useful. I also have a .net background and this was something I was looking for in Handlebars when I first started with it too. Just remember that your layout when using these helpers needs to be included in the assemble options as a partial for it to work properly.

We're working on cleaning up documentation so we don't have this type of confusion in the future.

Comment: That works, but it's a little bit weird that I need to put layouts in the partials directory.  What I did for my files was to create a "passthru" layout that has the DOCTYPE (since it needs to be first line), and a {{<body}}.  The rest of the template is then in the partial.

Comment: Yeah, agreed that it's a little strange, but... it's a necessary evil to workaround Handlebars limitations